# The use of 'weights' in lmer to incorporate variance of individual data points?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, weights

This is a question regarding the use of the 'weights' function in lmer.
Similar to the "weighted" approach discussed here for use in linear regressions:
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/ch07.pdf

I wanted to use the "weights" function in lmer (using lme4 package) to account for variance of individual measurements in my dataset (ie.weights= 1/SEofY^2). That being said, I am not sure if this is correct and wanted to see if anyone had opinions on this.